# How to make running powershell commands in batch faster?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

You can create **coloured text** in the command prompt, but when it runs it's really slow. Is there any way of making it faster?

My Code:

```
@echo off
cls
powershell write-host -fore Yellow -back Red "Merry" -NoNewLine
powershell write-host -fore Red -back Yellow "Christmas" -NoNewLine
powershell write-host -fore Yellow -back Red "To" -NoNewLine
powershell write-host -fore Red -back Yellow "Everyone" -NoNewLine
powershell write-host -fore Yellow -back Red "In" -NoNewLine
powershell write-host -fore Red -back Yellow "2020!" -NoNewLine
```

Comment: If speed is your main concern and you're using Windows 10, I _highly_ recommend using  [VT100 escape sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#text-formatting) instead of Powershell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Powershell is an external program, that has to be loaded each time it is used. So use it just once:

```
@echo off
cls
powershell write-host -fore Yellow -back Red "Merry" -NoNewLine; ^
write-host -fore Red -back Yellow "Christmas" -NoNewLine;^
write-host -fore Yellow -back Red "To" -NoNewLine;^
write-host -fore Red -back Yellow "Everyone" -NoNewLine;^
write-host -fore Yellow -back Red "In" -NoNewLine;^
write-host -fore Red -back Yellow "2020!" -NoNewLine
```

Powershell has to be loaded just once compared to 6 times before.

The `^`  at the end of the lines is a "Line continuation", so actually, this is just one long (logical) line, splitted into several (physical) lines for readabilty:

```
powershell write-host -fore Yellow -back Red "Merry" -NoNewLine;write-host -fore Red -back Yellow "Christmas" -NoNewLine;write-host -fore Yellow -back Red "To" -NoNewLine;write-host -fore Red -back Yellow "Everyone" -NoNewLine;write-host -fore Yellow -back Red "In" -NoNewLine;write-host -fore Red -back Yellow "2020!" -NoNewLine
```

Note, `cmd` has a maximal line length (about ~8k chars), which limits this method.

Comment: I put it in a batch file and it says:

^ : The term '^' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: doesn't happen here. But I can replicate your error by ending the lines with `^^` instead of just `^`. Please verify, there is just one `^` and it is the very last char on that (physical) line(s).

Comment: Question: do you start the batch file from a CMD window or from a Powershell Window?

Comment: the described error happens in a Powershell window; but it makes no sense to start powershell within powershell. Just use `write-host` in this case.